# Implementing DAO Pattern on Android project

Tags: android, database, design-patterns, dao

I'm developing an Android 3.1 and above.

I have the following packages:

[image]

`es.viacognita.models` contain classes to store data retrieved with a web service. When I get all web service data, I need to insert it on database.

To make it right, I've thought to use DAO pattern, but I don't know how to do it.

If I use DAO pattern, may I need to use `es.viacognita.models` classes? I think that these classes are going to be DAO classes, isn't it?

Where I have to implement inserts, updates, or deletes? on `DBManager` class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement inserts,updates,deletes and all other operations in DBManager class or create a seperate class dao which does all the operations you want to do on the database...

```
    public class DAO {
private SQLiteDatabase database,customdb;
private DBManager dbHelper;



public DAO(Context context) {
    dbHelper = new DBManager(context);
}
public void open() throws SQLException {
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

}
public void close() {
    dbHelper.close();
}
//insering,deleting and all other operations you want to perforem on the database
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have another question: how can I implement transactions? Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by transactions?inserting,deleting and other operations?

Comment: Yes. I have to insert a lot tables, and if one of them fails, I have to undo all previous inserts.

Answer (score 2):

I would use DBManager's namespace. I treat your model classes as business entity classes and create a separate library for DAO (DAL) layer. Using this methodology you are able to separate your business logic from your Data access layer.